# Close window programmatically

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nib, nsviewcontroller

For a **Cocoa application on a Mac** I need ti display some windows when the use click on the associated button. I can display the window using this :

```
-(void)popView:(NSString *)viewName {
    _windowController = [[NSWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:viewName];
    [_windowController showWindow:nil];
}
```

In the new window I have a `Push Button` "Cancel" and Another "Save". I want to perform some queries in a database when the "Save" button is pressed and close the window when the "Cancel" button is pressed.

I can close the window while dragin it from the `xib` file (The "outlet menu" when you right-click on the window)

But I can't use this for the "Save" button.

I tried `[self performSelector:@selector(performClose:)];` but I got an error message :

> [AddProductViewController performClose:]: unrecognized selector sent
>   to instance 0x107f64900

Same for `[[[self view] window] close];`

I lack of ideas how to solve it, this is my very first Mac application.

Comment: The error message tells you everything you need to know: `[AddProductViewController performClose:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x107f64900`  You are trying to send `performClose` to the view controller, and not the window controller.

Comment: I must instantiate a `WindowController` in the `ViewController`, link it to my view and perform the `perfomClose`?

Comment: No, you probably just need to use `[_windowController performClose]`.